# KeyError on import local function when ran more than once

Tags: python, python-import, keyerror

I have a script where at some point I have to to import another script.
I wrote but my entire script in pycharm without any problems. When running my script in spyder3 the first time everything goes smoothly but the second time I run the script I get a keyError on my import.
For example

```
import pipeline.bTest.cTest
pipeline.bTest.cTest.main()
```

errors on the second run with a KeyError: 'pipeline'

The first run always works but the second and any after that crash instantly with this error, and this only happens in spyder. Unfortunatly I need it to work in spyder.
What could be causing this?

```
runfile('/home/voreenpc/Documents/user/pipeline_3/run_pipeline_with_GUI.py')
Reloaded modules: tkfilebrowser, tkfilebrowser.filebrowser, tkfilebrowser.constants, tkfilebrowser.autoscrollbar, tkfilebrowser.path_button, tkfilebrowser.tooltip, tkfilebrowser.recent_files, tkfilebrowser.functions
True
True
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-5-bb711d6550c5>", line 1, in <module>
    runfile('/home/voreenpc/Documents/user/pipeline_3/run_pipeline_with_GUI.py')

  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/spyder_kernels/customize/spydercustomize.py", line 678, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)

  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/spyder_kernels/customize/spydercustomize.py", line 106, in execfile
    exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)

  File "/home/voreenpc/Documents/user/pipeline_3/run_pipeline_with_GUI.py", line 108, in <module>
    from pipeline.gui.tkinter_gui import run_gui

  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load

  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 963, in _find_and_load_unlocked

  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 906, in _find_spec

  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 1280, in find_spec

  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 1246, in _get_spec

  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 1115, in __iter__

  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 1103, in _recalculate

  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 1099, in _get_parent_path

KeyError: 'pipeline'
```

Comment: When you import like that you should use `as` or `from`: `import aTest.bTest.cTest as cTest` and `cTest.main()` **or** `from aTest.bTest import cTest`

Comment: That doesn't change anything for the error

Comment: Are those files, modules, or classes? Please paste the FULL error traceback.

Comment: You must be doing something funky or not sharing everything. It works fine for a base case: [see my code](https://repl.it/@Syntactical01/DeadHeartyDefinitions)

Comment: See edit for full error traceback

Comment: think you'll have to provide more code, what else is going on?

Comment: I have written a tkinter gui which asks the user for some settings and specifics about a pipeline. These settings are then written in the files and the file which calls the pipeline is called. I can't really show more code because of an nda. But the weird part is that pycharm has no problem with the code while spyder crashed but only after the first run is succesfull. I can't really go any deeper.

Comment: I would not recommend using Spyder. As an IDE it more or less sucks. I have seen countless questions with people having dumb issues like this on it. That being said your issue does not appear to be a import issue. When you import code, it runs the imported code and it looks like the code you are importing has a bug.

Comment: I totally agree with the fact that spyder sucks. Unfortunately most people in my institution use it

Comment: Most likely spyder is using one of its environments where things arent installed properly.